# Does the if clause modify "I will play the violin" even though the clauses are not next to each other?

Tags: conditionals

> I will play the violin when I am at the park if my fingers are not sore today.

Is the "if" clause modifying "I will play the violin" even though these clauses are not next to each other?

So that the sentence means:

> If my fingers are not sore today, I will play the violin when I am at the park.

I know using an "and" between both subordinate clauses would clear up the confusion, however, if there is no "and" does a "nesting" situation arise?

Comment: Yes, it does modify the whole clause; they don't need to be next to each other. By the way, _I will_ is very rare in real English; it's almost always contracted to _I'll_, and saying it draws attention to the speaker, instead of the topic. And nesting is not dependent on the presence or absence of _and_.

Comment: To clarify, the "if" clause cannot modify the "when" clause to the exclusion of the independent clause? It has to modify the independent clause that contains the subordinate "when" clause?

Comment: _To clarify_ is used to introduce statements. Those have the form of statements, but there are question marks after them? And whose statements or questions are they? I never said any of that.